# Where would an S3 upload speed cap originate?

Tags: windows, networking, amazon-s3

I do a *ton* of uploading to S3 and am experiencing capped speeds and I can't quite figure out how to address it.

The setup: Windows Server 2008 R2 x64, external HD, using a Java based upload tool called Jsh3ll and custom VBS scripts to kick the jobs off.

Running one process at a time, I am always limited to about 4mbps. I have FiOS at 35/35mbps speeds, so it isn't an outright limit. AND, I can run parallel instances and can go all the way up to 35mbps, so I know the problem isn't gateway/nic/machine/amazon related. Running parallel instances works to a degree as a solution, but increases the complexity of my workflow greatly. Solving this would make my life dramatically easier.

When I was first doing this I was playing around with a bunch of Windows TCP parameters and was able to briefly get unconstrained bandwidth, but it wasn't repeatable.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suspect you're seeing a [bandwidth-delay product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bandwidth-delay_product) (BDP) artifact. A "long, fat pipe" (high bandwidth, high latency) limits the amount of data that TCP can put "in flight" at any given time. Your observation that parallel transfers run faster is a big indicator of BDP coming into play.

What's your round trip latency to S3 look like?

You might try enabling [the Compound TCP Congestion Provider](http://research.microsoft.com/apps/pubs/default.aspx?id=70189) (CTCP) via the `netsh interface tcp set global congestionprovider=ctcp` command. This congestion provider is supposed to "aggressively" set the send window to put more data "in flight" on high bandwidth, high latency networks.

From the Microsoft Research paper:

> For TCP connections with a large TCP Receive Window size and a large bandwidth-delay product (the bandwidth multiplied by the latency of the connection), Compound TCP (CTCP) in the Next-Generation TCP/IP stack aggressively increases the amount of data sent at one time ... In testing performed internally at Microsoft, large file backup times were reduced by almost half for a 1 Gigabit-per-second connection with a 50-millisecond round-trip time. Connections with a larger bandwidth-delay product can have even better performance.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding, I wanted to make sure I had a reboot and was able to test under the same conditions.

It appears that this hasn't yet solved my problem. 

What else can I check? Tracert to S3 doesn't give me the full latency picture, but up to level3 in WA, I'm sub 30 ms.